# Получение элемента по его координатам BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

У меня есть html верстка, которую я валидирую с помощью BeautifulSoup, можно ли как-нибудь получить содержание тэга зная его координаты? Например на ширине экрана в 1400px?

```
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

price = parsed_html.findAll('span', class_='n7l')


print(price[0].text)
```

Comment: А зачем вам это? Мне кажется вам стоит поменять подход

Comment: Просто на сайте, который я пытаюсь парсить, класс нужного элемента постоянно меняется, поэтому я хочу попробовать получать его по координатам а не по классу

Comment: Может попробовать получать по xpath или иному селектору?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это сделать, используя один **BeautifulSoup**, но готовы ли вы написать свою библиотеку для представления страниц? BeautifulSoup сам по себе, лишь инструмент для редактирования и анализа. Нет такого магического способа, с помощью которого вы могли бы выпытать у него информацию о расположении элементов, поскольку он не умеет рендерить

Полагаю, что для ваших задач лучше использовать инструменты для тестирования Web-приложений, такие, как **Selenium** или **Puppeteer**, которые по сути своей являются программными библиотеками для управления браузером. В случае с Selenium делается всё достаточно просто:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
#Далее используем на странице функцию из JavaScript и возвращаем ответ в переменную element
element = driver.execute_script("return document.elementFromPoint(x, y);") #Вместо x и y подставляете координаты
```

Есть параметры для изменения размера окна, юзер агента, тестировать можно под все устройства, но это оставлю вам уже для личного изучения

Comment: Я использую ZenRowsClient для обхода cloudfare и антибота на сайте, есть ли здесь альтернативы?

Comment: Т е webdriver открывает браузер на моем пк, можно ли этого не делать?

Comment: нет, ведь он им управляет. Но можно передать параметр headless=True что не породит графического окна браузера.